# quit action not being executed from button

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a program that creates a GUI form:

```
win=Tk()
win.resizeable(width=True, height=True)
```

I have a quit button that was originally defined as:

```
quitButton=tk.Button(win,text="Quit", fg="red",underline=0, 
                     command=win.destroy)
```

When it was defined this way, the quit button worked quite well, shutting down the app and closing the window completely.

I wanted to wrap this in a dialog box to protect against unexpected checking of the quit button. I, therefore, created a `QuitAction` function to pop up a dialog box and verify that the user intended to press the button.

```
def QuitAction():
    qtitle = 'You pressed the quit button'
    qmessage = 'Any unsaved changes will be lost!\nDo you want to quit?'
    q = messagebox.askyesno(qtitle, qmessage)
    if q:
        win.destroy
```

When I replace `command=win.destroy` with `command=QuitAction`, the function executes (I get the dialog box),[dialog box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdL2j.jpg) but when I click the YES button (which should execute `win.destroy`), nothing happens.

If I replace `win.destroy` with any other code (e.g., `print('You pressed yes')`) it works just fine. If I make another referent to `win` (e.g.(`print(win.minsize())`), it works fine.

So I appear to be able to reference `win` from within my `QuitAction` function.

Why is `win.destroy` not executing?

Comment: you have to add `()` to execute command - `win.destroy()` (`command=` expected without `()` to execute it later)

Comment: `win.destroy` does not execute the same reason a mere `print`(for python3) wouldn't. You're just _mentioning_ the method/function rather than calling it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out...

When I changed

```
def QuitAction():
   qtitle = 'You pressed the quit button'
   qmessage = 'Any unsaved changes will be lost!\nDo you want to quit?'
   q = messagebox.askyesno(qtitle, qmessage)
   if q:
       win.destroy
```

to

```
def QuitAction():
   qtitle = 'You pressed the quit button'
   qmessage = 'Any unsaved changes will be lost!\nDo you want to quit?'
   q = messagebox.askyesno(qtitle, qmessage)
   if q:
       win.destroy()
```

everything worked - still getting used to Python.

Comment: This is because `command=` expects a reference to a function than to an immediate call, whereas you need an immediate call inside your dedicated method.